# 4.16 LAB: Warm up: Drawing a right triangle

Tags: python

This program will output a right triangle based on user specified height triangle_height and symbol triangle_char.

(1) The given program outputs a fixed-height triangle using a * character. Modify the given program to output a right triangle that instead uses the user-specified triangle_char character.

(2) Modify the program to use a loop to output a right triangle of height triangle_height. The first line will have one user-specified character, such as % or *. Each subsequent line will have one additional user-specified character until the number in the triangle's base reaches triangle_height. Output a space after each user-specified character, including a line's last user-specified character.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to create a space between my characters. Example input is % and 5. My code is:

```
triangle_char = input('Enter a character:\n')
triangle_height = int(input('Enter triangle height:\n'))
print('')

for i in range (triangle_height):
    print((triangle_char) * (i + 1))
```

my output is:

```
%
%%
%%%
%%%%
%%%%%
```

while expected output is:

```
% 
% % 
% % % 
% % % % 
% % % % %
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join). This would work:

```py
for i in range(triangle_height):
    print(' '.join(triangle_char * (i + 1)))
```

It is adding spaces between every character because strings are iterable.

This may be optimized a bit by having a list of the characters and appending 1 character in each iteration, rather than constructing `triangle_char * (i+1)` every time.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix the white space errors:

```py
for i in range(triangle_height):
    print(' '.join(triangle_char * (i + 1)) + ' ')
```

Comment: Seems identical to shriakhilc's answer

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(triangle_height+1):
     print(f'{triangle_char} '*i)
```

Answer (score 0):

I see the popular way so far is using join, but another way while trying to stay true to the original idea is you simply can add a white space after each character. See below:

```
triangle_char = input('Enter a character:\n')
triangle_height = int(input('Enter triangle height:\n'))
print('')

for i in range(triangle_height):
    print((triangle_char + ' ') * (i + 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some really good suggestions on here. Another approach is to use an incremented variable in a while loop as shown below:

```
triangle_char = input("Enter a character:\n")[0]
triangle_height = int(input("Enter triangle height:\n"))
i = 0

while (i <= triangle_height):
    print((triangle_char + ' ') * i)
    i += 1
```

With the example above, i iterates until it is equal to triangle_height and uses polymorphism to generate a quantity of (triangle_height + ' ') based on the value of i. This will generate the right triangle this lab requires. The space is used to format the triangle per lab requirements.

Another method is using the .join() feature, and it certainly would work well here, but is not taught until CH7 of this book where you learn about input and CSV files. I am unsure if your professor would approve of using this, and I am only saying this because my professor was strict about using material not covered.

An additional method mentioned already is to use a for loop with the use of the range() feature containing an expression:

```
triangle_char = input("Enter a character:\n")[0]
triangle_height = int(input("Enter triangle height:\n"))

for i in range((triangle_height + 1)):
    print((triangle_char + ' ') * i)
```

The end point of range() being just triangle_height would not suffice because the value specified as the end point is not included in the sequence. This would make a right triangle with a height of 4 even if triangle_height was 5 Therefore, you must use the expression (triangle_height + 1). From there, the output is set up similarly to my first solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a whitespace in the print statement.

```
height = int(input())
symbol = (input())
print()

for i in range(height):          #Loop for every index in the range 0-height
    print((symbol + ' ') * (i + 1))  #Add whitespace to symbol
```

Answer (score 0):

```
triangle_char = input('Enter a character:\n')
triangle_height = int(input('Enter triangle height:\n'))
print('')
ctrl = 1
while ctrl != triangle_height + 1:
    print(*ctrl*(triangle_char,),sep=' ',end=' \n')
    ctrl = ctrl +1
```

Here is what I used to solve this. Ockham's Razor

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(triangle_height):
     print(' '.join(triangle_char * (i + 1)), end=" \n")
```

This is my answer and it worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

`format()` method would work here as well:

```
for i in range(triangle_height + 1):
    print('{}{}'.format(triangle_char, " ") * i)
    i += 1
```